# Rails MultiSite App + nginx config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I'm trying to deploy a multisite Rails app with different views and public folders for each site. Let's say that we have www.foo.com and www.bar.com. Inside my RAILS_ROOT directory I have a [sites] directory with two folders inside [foo] and [bar] each folder consists of a [public] and [views] folder.

My nginx configuration has to be something like that:

```
server {
      listen 80;
      server_name www.foo.com;
      root RAILS_ROOT/sites/bar/public;
      passenger_enabled on;
      rails_env development;
}


server {
      listen 80;
      server_name www.bar.com;
      root RAILS_ROOT/sites/bar/public;
      passenger_enabled on;
      rails_env development;
}
```

My problem is that nginx can't actually find RAILS_ROOT as it expects a usual hierarchy for the public folder RAILS_ROOT/public. Any solution for this?

Comment: RAILS_ROOT is a variable of the rails framework. Nginx can't see it.

Comment: Can you post errors, etc?  This is the standard deployment for Rails on nginx; however, if you only have 'public' and 'views' folder (and don't have an unusual fcgi), passenger is probably unable to start the app because, er, tons of it is missing. ;)

Comment: Actually the problem is that nginx can't locate the core part of the app as it is located 2 parent directories more than the normal. Normally we have path/to/app/public whereas I have path/to/app/sites/foo/public. I need to tell nginx to look there to find the core rails app. How can I do that??

Answer (score 0):

When I referer to RAILS_ROOT I don't mean the variable I use it instead of writing a specific path .../.../